# Aligning item end (not start) to the key line in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, leanback

I use HorizontalGridView to display some items in a scrollable horizontal list.
My intention is to have a 'key line' almost at the end of the screen, so when I scroll right, items coming from the right align to that 'line', so focused item is at the same position.

I've already done it with this configuration:

```
windowAlignmentOffset = position of key line
focusScrollStrategy = FOCUS_SCROLL_ALIGNED
windowAlignmentOffsetPercent = WINDOW_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
itemAlignmentOffsetPercent = ITEM_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
```

My problem is that I want my items to be aligned to that line at the end of the item, not the start of the item.
My items have variable width, so I can't just subtract some value from key line position.
I think I may try to modify key line position for every focus change, but is there any easier solution for that?
An option for GridView or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it figured out.
I needed to change

```
itemAlignmentOffsetPercent = ITEM_ALIGN_OFFSET_PERCENT_DISABLED
```

to

```
itemAlignmentOffsetPercent = 100F
```

I think this moves the item more from the right edge by 100% of the item width.
Therefore item is aligned on its right edge to the 'key line'.

This is exactly what I wanted to achieve.